# How can I access output to stdout from a UWP console application in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, uwp, console, windows-10, stdout

I have created a test `C++ UWP` console application `("app3.exe")` in `Visual Studio 2017` that prints a string to `stdout`. When run on Command Prompt or PowerShell, I can see the output, but nothing else can. For example, I can write the command output with `app3.exe > a_file.txt` and it creates a blank file. **I suspect this has something to do with Windows wrapping the actual function** (the one with output to `stdout`) in another calling layer that has no output to `stdout`. I just want to be able to access the `stdout` output from my program. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is the sample code:

```c
int main()
{
    printf("This is output");
    std::cout << " to stdout.";
    return(0);
}
```

I've trimmed it down to the bare bones.

For what it's worth, I'm running on Windows 10 Pro version 1803, build 17134.915.

[image: Updated output.]

**Further explanation**

I want to get built-in sensor data (accelerometer, etc.) from a Microsoft Surface Pro into MATLAB. As I understand things, to access the sensors I need the UWP. I have tried all of the provided [UWP console application templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewWhitechapelMSFT.ConsoleAppUniversal&ssr=false#overview) with the same problem: no output registers from the command, as in the above image. Ideally I would run the application from MATLAB using the `system` command and parse the output there, however there is no output MATLAB or anything else (besides my own eyeballs) can detect when the application is run. After much trouble, I can write the output to a temporary file, but the location changes from device to device so telling MATLAB where to find it is nontrivial. I just want to be able to use the `stdout` output.

Comment: could you try `cout << "Some String";`? `printf` is really oldschool ;-)

Comment: Just tried it and updated the sample. Same behavior: I can see on the console, but nothing else can.

Comment: Please make the test output be text.

Comment: @AngerDensity: I mean replace your screenshot.

Comment: A bounty seems already given? What's the current status of this question?

Comment: Still unanswered. Now offering double the bounty.

Comment: The UWP is running in the sandbox and is different from the desktop app.This is by design for security reason.The C++ has full access, UWP does not.Can you tell us why you want to do this, what is the specific scenario? And why you want to access the stdout output from UWP application?

Comment: If you want to write a UWP console app (which is not a UWP app with console support...), it's possible since Windows 1803, but the manifest is a nightmare (it's actually getting worse w/o any proper documentation every day). I suggest you install these Microsoft-provided templates: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewWhitechapelMSFT.ConsoleAppUniversal&ssr=false#overview and it should work as is. Also see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp

Comment: @faywang I have updated the question to clarify things.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm using the templates you linked; I have tried all UWP/console app language combinations with the same result.

Comment: printf output works fine for me (winrt UWP console template, running from VS2017). I'm curious how do you run your app3.exe wich is supposed to be a UWP (so must be deployed,etc.). That being said, if you're running the latest Windows (1903) you don't need UWP to use (some) WinRT components, including sensor: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/#AQUkeyFYsUVWTmgf.97

Comment: Accessing sensors does not require UWP.  UWP is not needed at all. You can use the Sensor API. [ISensorManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sensorsapi/nn-sensorsapi-isensormanager)
  and [ISensor](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/api/sensorsapi/nn-sensorsapi-isensor) are your interfaces. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36124/Sensor-API-Make-your-Win32-applications-environmen) is one of my old articles.

Answer (score 4):

**2019/08/12 16:10 PM**

I apologize for previous answers being not really that much specific to `UWP`, I was unaware of all its details, and I was answering considering more the use of the `C++` language on the Windows platform in general.

So it turned out that `Universal Windows Platform` is a technology developed by Microsoft to allow developers write applications that runs on all Microsoft devices by accessing a common development and security model and a common `API`.

To be able to write `UWP` console applications you need to have installed in your Microsoft Visual Studio copy the [UWV Console Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewWhitechapelMSFT.ConsoleAppUniversal). After you've installed them, you'll need to create a new `Console App C++/CX (Universal Windows)`.

As you will see the template itself adds a `Program.cpp` file compiled with the following code:

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;

int __cdecl main(){

    wprintf(L"Command line arguments:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < __argc; i++){
        wprintf(L"__argv[%d] = %S\n", i, __argv[i]);
    }

    wprintf(L"Press 'Enter' to continue: ");
    getchar();
}
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp#add-your-code-to-main) is the reference to the UWP console example. As specified in the documentation, by dfault `UWP` applications won't be able to access the filesystem beside the folder they are run from and below. In order to broaden the access to other filesystem location you need to edit the application capability declaration `XM`L file by adding the `rescap` namespace and the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability as follows:

```xml
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Without further ado I advice you to carefully read the documentation about the subject at https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions to be able to achieve your goal.

As last note: when you will open the documentation with your browser by default it will show you `C#` code examples, which are not what you want. To see corresponding `C++` examples you have to select the language at the top of the page as the following screnshot shows:

[image: Changing the programming language of the examples]

---

**2019/07/30 6:41 PM**

Considering setting the Subsystem to Console from linker options did not solve your issue, I digged al litte more. By reading at the [Windows API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console) for creating a new console I found the following statements:

> A graphical user interface (GUI) or console process that is not currently attached to a console can use the `AllocConsole` function to create a new console. (GUI processes are not attached to a console when they are created. Console processes are not attached to a console if they are created using CreateProcess with DETACHED_PROCESS.)

So basically after having included the `Windows.h` header this is the workflow you should follow:

1. Create a console with [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole)
2. Get the standard output handle with [GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle)
3. Write on the console with [WriteConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole)
4. Release the console with [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/kingseva/a918ec66079a9475f19642ec31276a21) there is a full example that rebinds also C++ standard streams so that you can use directly them as usual in c++.

---

**2019/07/30 3:45 PM**

Did you try to set the `SUBSYSTEM` option in the solution properties or in the command line the `Linker` section?

```
/SUBSYSTEM:Console
```

It actually tells the Windows operating system how to execute the produced executable file. Specifically **this option influence the choice of the entry point operated by linker**. This  seems exactly the behaviour you are explaining in the question.

Comment: Glad to ear that!

Comment: Sorry for the approach: it's because I cannot reproduce your issue, anyway probably older printf() function should work, you get it by including cstdio. Can you try that?

Comment: I've updated the answer, with a different (hopefully for you definitive) solution.

Comment: The AllocConsole() command is failing, which seems to be an indicator that there is a console already attached. I'm trying to figure this out now.

Comment: Just a returned FALSE from AllocConsole().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197232/discussion-between-giovalomba-and-anger-density).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Output.\r\n");
```

Or you can try:

```
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
fprintf(stdout, "Output.\r\n");
```